# Adding a location to a javascript timetable

Tags: javascript, json, timetable

feel free to launch abuse at me if I have missed a question that expains this. I'm pretty new to JS aswell.

I'm building a timtable for shuttle buses to and from our offices. I wanted to add a new location.

My current code is this:

```
        function changeTimes (selectedOption) {

       var myTT = document.getElementById("timeTable");

       var myLocs = document.getElementById("Locations");

       if (selectedOption=='1') {

            myTT.innerHTML = brdepStr;

            myLocs.innerHTML = 'Bath Road';

       } else {

            myTT.innerHTML = badepStr;

            myLocs.innerHTML = 'Buckingham Avenue';
```

I then changed it to the following, which didn't work. Being a complete newbie to JS I'm guessing you can't have two "else" statements in a row?

```
        function changeTimes (selectedOption) {

       var myTT = document.getElementById("timeTable");

       var myLocs = document.getElementById("Locations");

       if (selectedOption=='1') {

            myTT.innerHTML = brdepStr;

            myLocs.innerHTML = 'Bath Road';

       } else {

            myTT.innerHTML = badepStr;

            myLocs.innerHTML = 'Buckingham Avenue';

       } else {
            myTT.innerHTML = bwdepStr;

            myLocs.innerHTML = 'Brunel Way' ;

    }
```

Really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: You're right. I don't think you can have 2 `else` in any language because it doesn't make sense. You probably wanted it to be and `else if` in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mkilmanas said, there can be no 2 `else` on the same if block (else will always be executed if all previous if/else if statements are not executed, so if you need 2 elses, you can just cut the code from the second else into the first else). Change the first else to `else if(selectedOption == '2')` and you should be okay for this part :)